# How to change UILabel.text in UIViewControler when anther UIViewController disimissed

Tags: swift, uilabel

I made a simple app with swift xcode 8.1
Where in the application I apply the function when viewcotroller dismissed then UILabel.text on previous viewcontroller changed.
But always the same.
What should I do, or how my app works like my plan.
thank you

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

protocol SetButtonUnitDelegate: class{
    func setUnit(numButton: Int,id: Int)
}

var inCategory = Int()
var inUnit = Int()

class ConvertViewController: UIViewController {
    static var unitData = DBManager.realm.objects(UnitModel.self).filter("catId == \(inCategory)").sorted(byKeyPath: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
    static var idUnit: Int = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var unit1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitDsc1Lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unit2Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var padCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputNumberLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitDsc2Lbl: UILabel!
    let unitId = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        setKeypad()
        setDefaultUnit()

    }
    //MARK: - Layout 
    func setKeypad() {
        let weidth = padCollectionView.frame.width
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let marginRL: CGFloat = 10
            let minspacing: CGFloat = 1.0
            let cellWeidth: CGFloat = (weidth / 4.0) - (minspacing + marginRL )
            let cellSIze = CGSize(width: cellWeidth, height: cellWeidth)
            layout.itemSize = cellSIze
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = minspacing
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: marginRL, left: marginRL, bottom: 1.0, right: marginRL)
            padCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
            padCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func setDefaultUnit()  {
        if inButton != 0 && inButton == 1 {
            print("buton pertama")
        }else if inButton != 0 && inButton == 2 {
            print("button ke dua")
        }else {
        unit1Button.setTitle(ConvertViewController.unitData[0].symbol, for: .normal)
        unitDsc1Lbl.text = ConvertViewController.unitData[0].unitName
        unit2Button.setTitle(ConvertViewController.unitData[1].symbol, for: .normal)
        unitDsc2Lbl.text = ConvertViewController.unitData[1].unitName
            print("buton awal")
        }
    }

    //MARK: - ACtion
    @IBAction func unit1Touch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showSubCat()
        inButton = 1
    }

    @IBAction func unit2Touch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showSubCat()
        inButton = 2
    }
    func showSubCat()  {
        let SVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "subCategoryTVC") as! SubCategoryTVC
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SVC)
        SVC.title = self.title
        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func keypadOnTamped(_ sender: KeypadUIButton) {
        let num: Int = (sender.indexpath?.row)!
        let curent = inputNumberLbl.text!
        switch num {
        case 0:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "7"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)7"
            }
            break
        case 1:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "8"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)8"
            }
            break
        case 2:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "9"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)9"
            }
            break
        case 3:
            inputNumberLbl.text = "0"
            break
        case 4:
            if curent == "0" {
            inputNumberLbl.text = "4"
            }else{
            inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)4"
            }
        case 5:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "5"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)5"
            }
            break
        case 6:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "6"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)6"
            }
            break
        case 7:
            if curent != "0" && (curent as NSString).length > 1{
                var aString: String? = curent
                aString = (aString! as NSString).substring(to: (aString! as NSString).length - 1)
                inputNumberLbl.text = aString
            }else if curent != "0" && (curent as NSString).length > 0 {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "0"
            }
            break
        case 8:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "1"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)1"
            }
            break
        case 9:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "2"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)2"
            }
            break
        case 10:
            if curent == "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "3"
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)3"
            }
            break
        case 11:
            print("roal back")
            break
        case 12:
            if curent.contains(".") == false {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)."
            }
            break
        case 13:
            if curent != "0" {
                inputNumberLbl.text = "\(curent)0"
            }
            break
        case 14:
            if curent.contains("-") {
                inputNumberLbl.text = curent.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
                print("dot seted")
            }else{
                inputNumberLbl.text = "-\(curent)"
            }
            break
        case 15:
            print("show setting")
            break
        default:
            print(num + 1)
        }
    }
}
//MARK: - UIColletionViewDataSourece
private let identifier = "converterCollectionViewCell"
extension ConvertViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 16
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = padCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! ConverterCollectionViewCell
        let index = indexPath.row
        cell.keypadButton.indexpath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
        cell.keypadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(keypadOnTamped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let keypad = cell.keypadButton!
        switch index {
        case 0:
            keypad.setTitle("7", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 1:
            keypad.setTitle("8", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 2:
            keypad.setTitle("9", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 3:
            keypad.setTitle("C", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 4:
            keypad.setTitle("4", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 5:
            keypad.setTitle("5", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 6:
            keypad.setTitle("6", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 7:
            keypad.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "btn_back"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 8:
            keypad.setTitle("1", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 9:
            keypad.setTitle("2", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 10:
            keypad.setTitle("3", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 11:
            keypad.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "btn_swap"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 12:
            keypad.setTitle(".", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 13:
            keypad.setTitle("0", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 14:
            keypad.setTitle("+/-", for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "bg_keypad"), for: .normal)
            break
        case 15:
            keypad.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
            keypad.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "btn_setting"), for: .normal)
        default:
            print("some ting error")
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension ConvertViewController: SetButtonUnitDelegate{
    func setUnit(numButton: Int,id: Int) {
        let data = DBManager.realm.objects(UnitModel.self).filter("id == \(id)").first!
        if numButton == 1 {
            unit1Button.setTitle(data.symbol, for: .normal)
            unitDsc1Lbl.text = data.unitName
        }else if numButton == 2 {
            unit2Button.setTitle(data.symbol, for: .normal)
            unitDsc2Lbl.text = data.unitName
        }else{
            print("noting for todo")
        }

    }
}
```

and in the second viewcontroller

```
    mport UIKit

var inButton = Int()

class SubCategoryTVC: UITableViewController {
    let subCat = DBManager.realm.objects(SubCategoryModel.self).filter("catId == \(inCategory)").sorted(byKeyPath: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
    weak var delegate : SetButtonUnitDelegate?
    let vc = ConvertViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return subCat.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subCat[section].haveUnit.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: SubCategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCell
        let unit = subCat[indexPath.section].haveUnit[indexPath.row]
        cell.symbolLabel.text = SubCategoryTVC.getSymbol(unitId: unit.id)
        cell.titleSymLabel.text = unit.unitName
        cell.dscLabel.text = unit.unitName
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "header") as? HeaderCell ?? HeaderCell(reuseIdentifier: "header")
        let catTitle = HomeCVController.getCategori[inCategory].catName
        let titleOfCat = "cat \(catTitle)"
        let catImage = titleOfCat.lowercased()
        let imageOfCat = catImage.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
        header.iconImage.image = UIImage(named: imageOfCat)
        header.titleLabel.text = subCat[section].subCatName
        header.section = section
        return header
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 70.0
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let idUnit = subCat[indexPath.section].haveUnit[indexPath.row].id
        self.delegate?.setUnit(numButton: 1, id: idUnit)
        inUnit = idUnit
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        showConverter()
    }
    func showConverter()  {
        let SVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "convertViewController") as! ConvertViewController
        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SVC)
        SVC.title = "some"
        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    static func getSymbol(unitId: Int)->String{
        let inSub = DBManager.realm.objects(UnitModel.self).filter("id == \(unitId)").first!
        var data: String = ""
        if inSub.symbol != "" {
            data = inSub.symbol
        }else{
//            data = inSub.unitName
            let aString = inSub.unitName
            do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%(.*)%", options: [])
            let tmp = aString as NSString
            var results = [String]()
                regex.enumerateMatches(in: aString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, aString.characters.count), using: {
                result,flags,stop in
                    if let range = result?.rangeAt(1){
                        results.append(tmp.substring(with: range))
                    }
                })
                if results.count == 0 {
                    let first = aString.components(separatedBy: " ")
                    data = first.first!
                }
            }catch{
                print("some ting error")
            }
        }
        return data
    }

}
```

Comment: Please put some code!

Comment: I've changed my question

Comment: that is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `UILabel` text when `UIViewController` dismissed by using `Delegate`.

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController, ChangeLabelDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewConfiguration()
        getAllDropDowns()
    }  

func buttonClick() {

    let secondViewController : SecondViewController ....
    secondViewController.delegate = self
}

func changeLabel() {
    // change Label Text here
}  

}

protocol ChangeLabelDelegate {
        func changeLabel()
    }
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: ChangeLabelDelegate?
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    } 

func changeLabel() {

    if (delegate) {
     delegate.changeLabel
}
}
```

Through this example code you can change `UILabel` text.

Comment: Alhamdulillah .. successful. Thank you very much